# Resolvent of the Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We know that the Laplacian $-\Delta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a radial operator. I was wondering if its resolvent $(\lambda - \Delta)^{-1}$ is also a radial operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I strongly suspect it should be, but cannot come up with a rigorous proof. Help, please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f = (\lambda - \Delta)^{-1} g \Leftrightarrow g = (\lambda - \Delta) f .$$
Now if we define $R_Af(x) = f(Ax)$ for any matrix $A$, then since $\Delta$ is a radial operator, for any orthogonal $A$ we have
$$ g = (\lambda - \Delta) f \Leftrightarrow R_A g = (\lambda - \Delta) R_A f .$$
Go from there.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!!

Comment: Sorry for asking a silly question, but what is a radial operator? Is $\Delta$ totally "radial", or purely "radial", or maybe just $\Delta=Rad(\Delta)$ is implied like in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-03/S0002-9939-02-06691-1/S0002-9939-02-06691-1.pdf

Comment: I took it to mean $\Delta = \text{Rad}(\Delta)$, or in my notation, if $A$ is orthogonal than $R_A^{-1} \Delta R_A = \Delta$.